# MariaDB dump create DB only

Tags: mysql, mariadb

How can I only dump the full db schema without any data. Including tables, views, functions, procedures and all that stuff. I have it with data, meaning it's scattered throughout the >2GB dump.

Comment: Read through `mysqldump --help`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the command line switch `--no-data` (http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/mysqldump/)

```
mysqldump --all-databases --no-data > all_databases.sql
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew that option existed but forgot how it was called. Have a great day!